# Round values to two decimal places

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to round decimal values to two decimal places.

Input:

```
<tab>
  <re>9.47499999/re>
  <re>-6.965111</re>
  <re>4.761</re>
</tab>
```

The output should be:

```
<fed>
  <rte>9.48/rte>
  <rte>-6.97</rte>
  <rte>4.76</rte>
</fed>
```

Tried code:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="tab/re > 0">
        <xsl:variable name="finround" select="number(format-number(tab/re,'0.000'))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(concat('+',format-number($finround,'0.00')),'%')"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="finroundsec" select="number(format-number(tab/re,'0.000'))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($finroundsec,'0.00'),'%')"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Results I am getting:

```
<fed>
  <rte>9.48/rte>
  <rte>-6.96</rte>
  <rte>4.76</rte>
</fed>
```

- `minus` value is not coming correctly. The correct answer is `-6.97`. But I am getting `-6.96`. How can I solve this?

I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: *The correct answer is `-6.97`.* Why?

Comment: I am getting the answer as `-6.96`. As the logic, the correct answer must be `-6.97`.

Comment: Do note that your are not using the well defined number functions [floor, ceiling, round](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Number-Functions) but a string representation function that in turn it is referenced in JDK 1.1 DecimalFormat

Comment: Please explain the logic by which `9.47499999` is rounded to `9.48`.

Comment: @Alejandro There is no  reference to JDK 1.1 DecimalFormat in XSLT 2.0. The behavior of the `format-number()` function is fully defined in the XSLT 2.0 specification itself.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I didn't see the last setence in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to round decimal values to two decimal places.
>
> .  .  .
>
> I am using XSLT 2.0

**Here is a correct and straightforward way to produce the rounding with the desired precision**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="re/text()">
    <xsl:sequence select="round-half-to-even(xs:decimal(.), 2)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be made well-formed!):

```
<tab>
    <re>9.47499999</re>
    <re>-6.965111</re>
    <re>4.761</re>
</tab>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<tab>
   <re>9.47</re>
   <re>-6.97</re>
   <re>4.76</re>
</tab>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Converting the string-value of the text node to `xs:decimal` -- not doing this will convert to `xs:double` -- which often results in loss of precision.
2. Using the standard XPath 2.0 function **[`round-half-to-even()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-round-half-to-even)**